# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Sales_Model_Order' not found in ....core/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Order/Collection.php on line 456

Tags: magento, fatal-error, magento-1.9.1

I was installing `magento 1.9.1` on my server everything went fine but after installation when i click on `Go to Backend` and give my username and password to login to Admin Panel it gives the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Sales_Model_Order' not found in
>   /home2/siatel/public_html/4ebay/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Order/Collection.php
>   on line 456

Though my frontend side of website is working perfectly ... Please help.
I can see my admin log-in page. Error comes only when I give username and pass and hit continue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information, it sounds like you're missing your

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

file.  It seems like you're missing a lot of different files as well.  I'd diff your installation vs. the contents of a standard tar archive.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance... after placing this file, now I'm getting this error:
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Sales_Helper_Data' not found in /home2/siatel/public_html/4ebay/app/Mage.php on line 547

Comment: @muqaddasshahzad: Now you need to make sure the file `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Helper/Data.php` does exist.

Comment: @muqaddasshahzad Seems like you're missing a bunch of files. I suspect you uploaded things incorrectly.  I'd start there.  Also, thanks for the upvote! :)

Comment: Hello,
Thank you so much, I'm into to magento... and you are right I might missed some files as I've uploaded through FTP with very unstable internet connection... 

does it mean, I still may suffer more errors even I'm into Control Panel?

Comment: Ah.. now when i click System>Configuration option it gives following error: 
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Shipping_Helper_Data' not found in /home2/siatel/public_html/4ebay/app/Mage.php on line 547

could you please tell me the way that how do you know I'm missing files and where I'm missing? if I could know then I can place all without bothering you more....

Comment: Might be. Some errors will popup immediately, when we try to access a new page. While some errors trigger only when a missing file is requested and needed to use by magento. It depends

Comment: Could you please tell me how can i get to know which file is missing.. please take my current error into account and tell me how do i can know which file is missing and where?

Comment: As @AlanStorm said, it seems that your system misses a bunch of files. You may need to install magento  again or need to check each and every page of admin

Comment: AH, it took about 5 hours to copy installation files from my local system to my server through FTP ... Do i must have to do again or is there any other way out?

Comment: I added an answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Your error shows like this

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Shipping_Helper_Data' not found in
>   /home2/siatel/public_html/4ebay/app/Mage.php on line 547

see the portion `'Mage_Shipping_Helper_Data' not found`. It means Magento is looking for a helper class file and it couldnt find it. Magento will look for this file in `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Helper/Data.php`.

I will give you some hint on how this file path came from. First of all magento core files lies in the location `app/code/core/`. Then missing class name (in this case `Mage_Shipping_Helper_Data`) will converted as `Mage/Shipping/Helper/Data.php`. Then this will append to the `core` codePool directory path. That is `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Helper/Data.php`

For every file, magento assigns path as like this. Please note that, you need to attach `.php` part to the last keyword. Also you need to copy the exact same data of that file (take into consider the version). It means it need to have a 'Magento way' class name and so on

Comment: That is absolutely right, and I know that it has missed lot of files, i can see there isn't some folders even showing...

I don't know how do I can thumps up on both of your replies... Anyways very much grateful

Comment: One thing that you can do is, check each and every core modules of magento with a fresh copy of magento 1.9.1 that are available in github.(https://github.com/speedupmate/Magento-CE-Mirror). But the best way is remove all existing file and then re-do installation. There may be other solutions. Ask @alanstorm. He is a genius. I have studied a lot from him and I am his big fan  :)